# (Discord py) Music bot does not take any commands

Tags: discord, discord.py

It is my first time posting here so I'm sorry if something is missing. I have set up three commands (join, play, leave) as of now to get it working. I have spent a few hours figuring out a problem with the bot as it is not taking any commands. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks already.

So whenever someone gives the bot a command, I get this error:

Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
          await ctx.send("Not in channel")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
          await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
          await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def p (self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5','options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube.dl.YouTubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

This is my main file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
   cogs[i].setup(client)



client.run("*my bot here*")
```

Comment: Did you register your cog properly in the main file?

Comment: I think so. Ill add my main file in the post.

Comment: You need to load cogs with `load_extension`. I have posted an answer with some code that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment above, to load cogs you need `load_extension`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20load%20extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension

This here should work:

```py
cogs = ['music']

for i in cogs:
   client.load_extension(f'cogs.{i}')
```

This assumes that you saved your `music` cog in a folder named `cogs`. If you use a different name, change the `cogs` in the line `client.load_extension(f'cogs.{i}')` with whatever you are using, or leave it out entirely if they are in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented this. I left out cogs from the line since they both are in the same folder. However, when I give commands to the bot i still get this error: Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found

Comment: @Petu Oh, is the indentation in the post the same as in your file? If so you need to indent your commands one less time. They need to be in the same indentation level as `def __init__(self, client):` and right now they are at the same level as `self.client = client`. Sorry I didn't catch that earlier. In general the indentation seems kind of all over the place, sometimes you use 2 spaces, sometimes 4. I would recommend to stick to one choice.

Comment: That was it, I redid the indents and it works, thanks a ton!